# How to include 0 (int) results in COUNT aggregate? PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
INSERT INTO Luisteraar(nummerId, oordeel) VALUES
(4,'good'),
(4,'not-rated'),
(5,'good'),
(5,'good'),
(6,'bad'),
(6,'good'),
(6,'good'),
(7,'not-rated'),
(7,'not-rated'),
(8,'bad'),
(8,'good')
```

so if i do this:

```
SELECT l.nummerid, count(l.oordeel) as manyGood 
FROM luisteraar l 
WHERE l.oordeel = 'good'
GROUP BY l.nummerid
```

Output:

```
nummerid  manyGood
 4            1
 5            2
 6            2
 8            1
```

problem: I also want nummerid 7 with manyGood = 0 in my output. How can i do this in PostgreSQL

Comment: My bad forgot to translate the last word leuk means good in dutch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation instead of a `WHERE` clause:

```
SELECT l.nummerid,
       count(l.oordeel) FILTER (WHERE l.oordeel = 'good') as manyGood 
FROM luisteraar l 
GROUP BY l.nummerid
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than using a subquery, just for the record.  Both more concise and better performing.

Answer (score 1):

Subquery against same table will work but there might be a better way

```
SELECT nummerid, 

(SELECT count(*) FROM luisteraar WHERE nummerid= l.nummerid AND oordeel= 'leuk') as manyGood 

FROM luisteraar l 

GROUP BY nummerid
```

Comment: That returns something completely different: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=156f117fbc5981a113c7ddbcbf5aa654